# Solving for the number of digits in large exponent problems

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

I'm studying for state Mathcounts and found this problem solution in the 2014 state test:

> 24. How many digits are in the integer
>     representation of 2^30?
>     Looking at the powers of 2, we have
>     2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048,
>     4096, 8192, 16384, 32768...
>     The number of digits in each can be
>     written as:  1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 etc.
>     Therefore, the number of digits needed to
>     represent 230 is 10.

The numbers with 4 digits in the list provided obviously do not follow this rule:
1024 2048 4096 8192

However, the answer of 10 is correct, as 2^30 is 1073741824, which has 10 digits.

Note that calculators are not allowed on this test.

**Is this process correct by some weird reasoning, or is the solution just lucky?**

Also, my original solution included an experimental logarithm I performed.
Log 2 of 10 yielded 3.32192809489, which I think means 2 to the power of 3.32193 is 10. Since each power of 10 includes 3.32192809489 powers of 2, I divided 30 by this ratio, yielding 9.03089986992. This would mean that 10 to the power of 9.03089986992 is approximately 2^30, which I verified with a calculator. Unfortunately this is not a viable way to solve without a calculator.

**If the Mathcounts official solution is incorrect, is there a more practical solution to this problem without a calculator?**

Comment: You can rewrite $2^{30} = (10^{3} + 24)^{3} = 10^{9}(1 + \frac{24}{1000})^{3}$ which makes it easier to see why it is a ten digit number. Now $(1 + \frac{24}{1000})^{n}$ becomes two digit number when n is around 100. However, it goes to infinity as n approaches infinity.

Comment: To pose the problem in a quick way: Is there a reliable way to estimate $\log_{10} 2^{n}=n \frac{\log 2}{\log 10}$ to the nearest integer (rounded up) without using a calculator?

Comment: @quantinho, thanks for the explanation. I see how breaking 2^30 into (2^10)^3 = 1024^3 could make this problem very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Breaking 2^30 into (2^10)^3 = 1024^3 makes this a simple estimation of the number of digits in 1024^3, which is 10.

**I would still like to know if the answer provided by Mathcounts is a possible solution.**